# Getrid of Logo box and title on Shrepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-logo, title

I was wondering if there was a way if i can get rid of the logo box and page name on the upper left corner of my page site. I am working with SharePoint Online and I think this would make my page cleaner.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On classic pages you can hide them using css, but that option is not available on modern pages

Same approach as this one which is for classic lists 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a26af6dd-f15f-4461-a10e-1e62f517ea46/sharepoint-online-how-to-hide-the-sharepoint-logo-on-a-list-using-css-or-jquery?forum=sharepointgeneral